# R csv file object not found. Extract variables

Tags: r, object, csv

i am doing some regression models in grad school. I recently stumbled over R. 
I have my .csv file in R and the regression works out fine. 
But I don't know how to extract the variables in the data frame so that I can use

```
summary(visits)
```

I get the error

```
Error in summary(visits) : object 'visits' not found
```

I appreciate every answer. 
Thanks

Edit 9/5:
My code looks something like this:

```
pool <- read.csv("Econ205A_Assigment_4_9.csv",sep=";", dec=",")
poolreg <- lm(visits ~ fee + pop + income, data = pool)
summary(visits)
```

The data frame looks like this

city visits  fee income    pop
1     1 168590 0.00  20600  36879
2     2 179599 0.00  33400  64520

My problem is that R doesn't treat any of the different observations as variables. So I get the error shown above.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a reproducible example for this example, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Otherwise this question is essentially impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I hope me edit made things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a summary of variables in database use,

```
mydata<-read.csv("yournameofcsvfile.csv") # reading the csv file assuming the csv file is in your working directory
```

`summary(mydata$visits)`  # assuming visits is a variable

Or:

```
 summary(mydata["visits"])
```